# Any real-world inspiration for the countries in the Black Magician series?

Tags: inspiration, trudi-canavan, black-magician

Trudi Canavan's Black Magician series, starting with [*The Magicians' Guild*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magicians%27_Guild) and continuing with the first trilogy and then a prequel novel and sequel trilogy, is set in a purely fantasy world consisting of several countries such as Kyralia, Sachaka, Elyne, etc.

**Are these countries in any way inspired by real-world countries?** Has the author commented on, or can we figure out from textual clues, any connections with specific real-world polities (current or former) that share enough similarities with the fictional ones that we can be reasonably sure of a direct connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canavan has stated her inspiration for at least **two** of the countries found in the Black Magician Series.

Most of the action takes place in Kyralia, and accordingly that is described in most detail. From an [AMA on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/26l6h9/hi_trudi_canavan_here_ama/), Canavan relates:

> One thing I did for the BMT *[Black Magician’s Trilogy]* was borrow a
> historical children's book about Japan from the library and copied
> down all the headings and subheadings, then filled in and filled out
> what I knew about the world under them. I ended up with a 20K word
> document and only used about 10% of it in the book, but it was a very
> useful prompt for fleshing out a world as well as learning how much
> information I really needed to give a reader to make the world seem
> well fleshed out.

From [Canavan’s website](https://www.trudicanavan.com/book-faqs/#worldBMT) we  learn:

> For the architecture, food and furniture *[of Kyralia]* I took
> inspiration from Japanese culture. The Sachakan culture is vaguely
> inspired by classical Rome – as an empire that has faded but, in this
> case, magic was able to sustain a form of slavery.

**So Kyralia was inspired by Japanese culture, and Sachaka by classical Rome.**

[image: Map of the Allied lands]

The remaining countries and cultures are not described with such care, and seem to be classified mainly by skin color. From *The Ambassadors Mission*, for example, we read the description of Shari Tariko:

> His skin was the typical Sachakan brown – lighter than a Lonmar’s but
> darker than an Elyne’s honey-brown.

Proceeding from lightest to darkest we have:

- Lan (pale hair, blue eyes, tall, tattoos, cold mountainous climate,
  warrior clans)
- Kyralia (dark hair, dark eyes, pale skin) - known to be based on Japan.
- Elyne (honey brown skin, red curly hair, short stature, “frivolous”, enjoy wine)
- Vin islands (pale brown skin, straight brown hair, brown or amber eyes, short in stature easy-going)
- Sachakan (brown skin, dark hair, excessive jewellery, body piercings) - known to be based on the Roman Empire
- Lonmar (dark brown skin, black curly hair, green or amber eyes, drab clothes, hot climate, conservative religion, hatred of homosexuality.)

There are also the inhabitants of Duna who lead a nomadic life in an inhospitable desert of volcanic ash.

I would speculate that the Lan are based on northern Europeans, possibly Vikings, and the Lonmar seem to be a kind of generic Arab culture. I have not been able to find any further statements by Canavan, however, which would confirm or deny this.